# Flow through a pipe using Bernoulli equation - Real industrial application using pressure monitors

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

This is not a homework question or off topic so please do not delete as previously done. I'm working in industry and need assistance on the real application.

I aim to calculate the flow through a pipe connecting an elevated pit (with water height from pipe inlet invert h1) to a large pond/lake, the pipe outlet is submerged and the height of water from the pipe invert is h2. 
I believe I need the Bernoulli equation but I can't see how it works when both sides aren't atmospheric pressure and hence don't cancel. We are measuring the pressure at both ends, hence height of water from the pipe inverts using submerged pressure transducers.

other notable point: The pipe ends are under water so not atmospheric pressure even thought he pond and pit surface is at atm pressure. 
Any help on how to input the head of water/pressure at each end to calculate the flow would be much appreciated. [image: Flow problem and potential equation]

Comment: Draw how it looks in reality.

Comment: If the pipe is straight then this should be a standard engineering problem. What's the catch?

Comment: Perhaps you will find what you need here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_flow

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation

Comment: What is your assessment so far?  Show us your equations and analysis

Comment: You don't need atmospheric pressure for the Bernoulli equation, you can simply follow a streamline from the entrance of the pipe to the exit, additionally accounting for friction losses. You should supply though further information on what the system looks like, what precisely you want to calculate and some more of your thoughts on how to solve it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I have drawn a picture and taken a picture. How do I upload this to the comment?

Comment: @Hachman Go into edit mode, click on picture icon in menu header.

Comment: @sammygerbil thank you.

Comment: I have now added the picture of my application including what I think maybe the velocity derivation. However i'm not sure because this came from the second scenario I've drawn which made several assumptions. These assumptions may not hold true for my real application. I'm measuring pressure/water height at both ends and i'm told you can use Bernulli to calculate flow

Comment: The Bernoulli equation assumes no frictional losses, so it isn't appropriate for this problem.  The following link will require quite a bit of reading and study, but it contains enough information to answer your question:https://www.kau.edu.sa/Files/0057863/Subjects/Chapter%208.pdf

Comment: This is an engineering problem. First, define a control volume and apply the continuity equation and momentum equation. Then solve.

Comment: thank you @DavidWhite.That really helps. I think I now have the solution!